# Cookie Authentication instead of JWT Bearer Token after a successful Oauth2 Login in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, cookies, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using [callicoder](https://github.com/callicoder)'s [spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo](https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo)
 sample to implement a rest api using Oauth2 client. Sample works without a problem.

However after a successful Oauth2 authentication, I want to issue a cookie instead of JWT Token to secure access to my controllers. In order to do this, I added the lines below `determineTargetUrl` on `OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. This sets a cookie containing JWT token created by `TokenProvider`.

```
CookieUtils.addCookie(response, appProperties.getAuth().getAuthenticationCookieName(), token, (int) appProperties.getAuth().getTokenExpirationMsec());
```

And then I created a `CookieAuthenticationFilter` similar to `TokenAuthenticationFilter` which checks the cookie set by `OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

```
public class CookieAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private AppProperties appProperties;

    @Autowired
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            Optional<String> jwt = CookieUtils.getCookie(request, appProperties.getAuth().getAuthenticationCookieName()).map(Cookie::getValue);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(String.valueOf(jwt)) && tokenProvider.validateToken(String.valueOf(jwt))) {
                Long userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromToken(String.valueOf(jwt));

                UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserById(userId);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Could not set user authentication in security context", ex);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and on `SecurityConfig` I replaced `tokenAuthenticationFilter` bean to `cookieAuthenticationFilter`

`http.addFilterBefore(cookieAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`

When I run the project, Oauth2 authentication is made successfully and cookie is set. However when I request a secured controller method, `CookieAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal` is not hit and request directly goes to `RestAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence` and exception is thrown with message `Full authentication is required to access this resource` .

Do I have to change any more configuration to change authentication to cookie from Bearer (JWT)?

Comment: hi, did you add @Component annotation to your CookieAuthenticationFilter ? also can you share your SecurityConfig file ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a result of a missing exception without catch. The sample and the code works as expected.